# Can't delete rows in Spark R data frame

Tags: r, apache-spark, delete-row, sparkr

**Context**

I'm working on sparkR with csv files. before working with spark, i was working on R with Excel files and I used to manipulate my tables with R to clean my datas.
I'm trying to delete the first 2 rows of a file but i didn't found a way to do it.

I tried with `subset` and `filter` but nothing works because i don't know how to specify that i want to remove the first 2 rows.

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Are you able to post a sample of the data to SO? If you can provide a reproducible example with data, it will help people answer your question.